# Mocha js Calling After() too Soon?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

New to Mocha unit testing, I have a few Mocha examples that are running fine, but I have been trying for hours to get this one to run and no matter what I do, after() is called way earlier than I feel it should. Here's an example:

```
var dummyData = require('./dummyData.js')

describe('mochaTest', function() {

    after(function(done) {
        dummyData.cleanDb(function(){
            done();
        })
    });

    it('should hit the db to get dummy data and send', function(done) {

        dummyData.createDummyData(function(data1, data2, Lookup) {
            Lookup.lookup({
                data1: data1,
                data2: data2
            }, function(err, result) {
                done();
            });
        });
    });
})
```

And then in dummyData.js:

```
exports.createDummyData = function(cb){
   doSomeStuff(function (err, patient) {
     // Connect to db, get some data to pass.
        var Lookup = require(./Lookup.js);
        cb(data1, data2, Lookup);

   })
}

exports.cleanDb = function(cb) {
   // Clear db connections.
   cb();
}
```

The problem is that right after the test is run, the after() function gets called and the Lookup function can't hit the db, because the db connection has been cleared. Why is after being called so early, it shouldn't be called until the it statement calls done() right?

Comment: shouldn't it be `require("./Lookup.js")` , also can you put a `console.log(err, result);` before you call `done()` in test case and tell what you get?

Comment: If you remove your `after` hook, does the test then work?

Comment: Yes if I remove after the test works, but of course the stuff in after is necessary to be called after everything is done.

Comment: I know this is over a year old but this is happening to me right now.  I have a test that increments a value in my Firebase database and then my after() resets it back to 0.  When I run the test I have Firebase open and I see the 0 jump to 1 and then quickly jump back to 0.  Removing the After function makes the test pass but I need that reset in order to continually run the test.   I guess I could reset on before() instead but after should still no work _that_ fast

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I have experienced the same issue and could not find any explanation to solve this. Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to answer as a comment, so I'll share how I solved my issue here.

In my controller, I had a method outlined as follows:

```
exports.insert = (request, response) => {
    UserModel.createUser(request.body)
        .then(() => {
            respond.status(201).send({message: 'User created successfully
        });
};
```

I realized the issue here, was that my test method wasn't waiting for a response from my `User.insert()`, because this function is void -- it does not return a value. So the following test would jump straight to calling `done();` since there was no reason to wait for a response from `User.insert()`. This was causing my after hook to run prematurely and close the connection to my database before my `UserModel` could populate.

```
// Code is shortened, but my request and response was formed using node-mocks-http package

it('should return status 201', function (done) {
    User.insert(request, response);
    assert(response._getStatusCode() === 201);

    done();
};
```

I hate to say how long this took me to realize this. But, I needed to return a promise from my controller, so that my test function would have something to wait on. By changing my controller to this:

```
exports.insert = async (request, response) => {
    await UserModel.createUser(request.body)
        .then(() => {
            response.status(201).send({message: "User created successfully"});
        })
        .catch(() => {
            response.status(400).send({message: "There is already an account with that email"});
        });

    return response;
```

And with my test looking something like this:

```
it('should return a status code of 201', async function () {
        await User.insert(request, response);
        assert(response._getStatusCode() === 201);
    });
```

The database populates successfully, and my test will wait for my promise to fulfill, thus updating the response before calling my assert. Then the after hook works when expected.

I hope this helps someone else who stumbles across this old thread.

Comment: Really scratched my head with this one. Great explanation @TylerSingleton!

Comment: In case anybody is wondering how to return a promise from a database/firestore triggered function. My approach, after reading this, has been to simply call either `Promise.resolve()` or `Promise.reject()` in the end of the function. And that has solved all of my problems with "after" running too soon.