# Mocha test execution moves to cleanup function too soon

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, mocha.js

I have a function wrapper in `alertTest.js` for calling `it` (OOP required by the architecture team):

alertTest.js:

```js
import { BaseTest } from "../base/BaseTest.js";
import { MainPage } from "../pages/MainPage.js";
import { Driver } from "../driver/Driver.js";
import { assert } from "chai";

export class AlertTest extends BaseTest {
  run() {
    console.log('here 1');
    it("Alerts", async () => {
      console.log('here 2');
      const mainPage = new MainPage();
      assert.isTrue(await mainPage.isPageOpen(), "Main page is did not open");
    });
  }
}
```

When I call `run` from `main.js`, execution moves out of `it` call to the `BaseTest.afterEach` function too soon (I think this is because I'm using `async/await`.

main.js:

```js
import { AlertTest } from "./alertTest.js";
import { BaseTest } from "../base/BaseTest.js";

BaseTest.beforeEach(); // logs "in before"

const alertTest = new AlertTest();
alertTest.run();

BaseTest.afterEach(); // logs "in after"
```

The order of console logs is the following:

```
in before
here 1
in after
here 2 (at this point driver instance is cleaned up and code fails)
```

How can I make sure pre/post conditions and the tests run sequentially? What is the problem here?

I tried wrapping the `run` in a promise and using `await alertTest.run()` but Mocha didn't recognize any functions to run ("passed 0" in output). Not sure if this is a correct approach.

```js
run() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    it("Alerts", async () => {
      const mainPage = new MainPage();
      assert.isTrue(await mainPage.isPageOpen(), "Main page is did not open");
      await mainPage.clickDivCard();
      resolve()
    });
  })
}
```

Changed snippet in main.js:

```js
await alertTest.run(); // <---
BaseTest.afterEach();
```

I saw this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31281328](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31281328/mocha-js-calling-after-too-soon) but still not sure how to apply fixes to my code.

Comment: "*OOP required by the architecture team*" - it sounds like they have no idea. These really should be plain functions.

Comment: Mocha will wait for the promise that your `it` callback returns. You should register `beforeEach` and `afterEach` into a [mocha hook](https://mochajs.org/#hooks). Don't build your own testing framework (`BaseTest` and all that) when you already have one.

Comment: I understand. Will try to see other possibilities. Also, was I going anywhere with the Promise wrapper in the `run` function?

Comment: Probably not. If mocha works like most other test runners, `it` only declares the test, it doesn't actually run it. So if you try to run multiple tests, this doesn't work at all.

Comment: If anything, you should try putting your `this.beforeEach()` and `this.afterEach()` calls right inside the `it` callback. Do it as a decorator around the actual test code.